# Configuring URL rewrite in Core to fetch swagger, API and an Angular rerouting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to achieve the following behavior in my Core 2 application. If the URL is:

- like */swagger*, then go to */swagger* (unchanged path),
- like */api/.**, then go to */api/.** (unchanged path),
- like anything other, then go to */index.html*.

I've been trying combinations of the following theme.

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
  .AddRewrite("^swagger$", "/swagger", true)
  .AddRewrite("(^api/.*)", "$1", true)
  .AddRewrite(".*", "index.html", true)
);
```

This doesn't seem to work. Swagger gets repeatedly more */swagger* parts, the API gets nothing in return. I'm rather unclear on the correlation between the code and the behavior. The last parameter is supposed to stop more rules from running but it seems not to be the case.

(If it's of any importance, I'm trying to get the routing in my Angular app to work.)

Comment: Why are you rewriting the URL instead of just configuring the routes?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Because I've got it running previously using web.config and under Core, I've found [this blog](https://www.softfluent.com/blog/dev/Page-redirection-and-URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET-Core), also supported by [this dude](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Aug/07/Handling-HTML5-Client-Route-Fallbacks-in-ASPNET-Core#URL-Rewriting-on-the-Host-Web-Server). Also, at the moment, I want to master the concept by making it work that way. However, I'm also pragmatic, so if you have a better idea, feel free to shoot!